# Update input text in react bootstrap typeahead from javascript/react

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

Hello I'm trying to create a react bootstrap typeahead in which I can update my input text from javascript. It works in console but doesn't work in code.

```
let typeaheadInput = document.getElementById('exTypeahead')
typeaheadInput.value = typeaheadInput.value + 'some text'
```

Is there any other way where we can insert text in the typeahead input box

```
import React from 'react';
import { Typeahead } from "react-bootstrap-typeahead";

const data = [
    {id: 1, fullName: 'John'},
    {id: 2, fullName: 'Peter'},
    {id: 3, fullName: 'Blaszczykowski'},
    {id: 4, fullName: 'lewandowski'},
]

class TypeaheadComp extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            selectedList: []
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <Typeahead
                id="basic-example"
                onChange={(selected) => {
                    let temp = [];
                    selected.map(x => {
                        temp.push(x);
                    });
                    this.setState({selectedList: temp})

                }}
                options={data}
                placeholder="Select name or create full name"
                selected={this.state.selectedList}
                labelKey="fullName"
                multiple
                allowNew
                newSelectionPrefix="Enter full name: "
                inputProps={{id:'exTypeahead'}}
            />;
    }
}

export default TypeaheadComp
```

Comment: You can execute the same js code in componentDidMount()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `defaultInputValue` prop can be used to set the input value on the *initial render*, but the component [intentionally does not provide](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/issues/266) a public API for setting the input value in a controlled manner.

**Workarounds**

**Note**: Both of these workarounds are highly discouraged.

1. You could leverage `defaultInputValue` by un-mounting and re-mounting the component (eg: by changing the key) with a new default input value on each new mount. This is pretty heavy-handed and could lead to performance issues or bugs.

```
const [key, setKey] = useState(0);
const [value, setValue] = useState('');

return (
  <Typeahead
    ...
    defaultInputValue={value}
    key={key}
    onBlur={(e) => {
      setValue('some value');
      setKey(key + 1);
    }}
  />
);
```

2. You could access the component instance with a ref and use the `setState` method to update the component state's `text` key. This is obviously not recommended since `setState` is private, is very fragile, and could break at any time

```
const ref = useRef(null);

return (
  <Typeahead
    ...
    onBlur={() => {
      ref.current.setState({
        text: 'some value',
      });
    }}
    ref={ref}
  />
);
```

Comment: can you please provide any references to why the workarounds are highly discouraged?

Comment: @gawkface: Not sure what kind of references you're looking for. In each case, I described the downsides of using the given approach. In the second case especially, you'd be accessing a private method, which is generally pretty bad.

Comment: sorry, I jumped to the linked discussion and did not pay attention. Thanks for the reply!