# Keep two react-bootstrap-typeahead inputs in sync

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

So I have an application with a dashboard and a main page that has a header. Both of them have a react-bootstrap-typeahead input to perform the same action - a search to open something on a map.

What I would like to achieve is:

1. when the user search something on the dashboard, the main page opens with the search result and on the header, the search input there shows what was searched on the other component.
2. on the other hand, when the user search something on the search input on the main page header, and then goes back to the dashboard, the dashboard search input should be prefilled with the value previously searched on the main page.

What I have tried so far:

So when the user picks a search item result, that string is saved on the application state using redux. I also clear it manually when the user clicks on the clear search button. The RBT component is defined to use this variable, as in:

```js
<AsyncTypeahead defaultInputValue={props.currentSearchValue} ... />
```

This seams to work on the first time, i.e. when the user has not interacted with the other input yet. For example, with the application on a fresh state (just loaded) if on the dashboard I pick a search item, when going to the main page because that search input has not been touched yet. Then, when I pick a search item on the main page and go back to the dashboard, I wouldn't see it because setting defaultInputValue is not enough, as that input is not in its default state anymore.

Any tips? I have been running in circles so far. Tried the [`key`/`setKey` workaround as described in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66170215/update-input-text-in-react-bootstrap-typeahead-from-javascript-react/66193042#66193042), but that wasn't enough to cover the case described on the previous paragraph. I also tried comparing the input value to the recorded value, but naturally when starting to typing with the input field the values would be different and therefore I cannot trigger a component reload based on that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something about your use case, the `selected` prop should do what you need. You can save the selected item(s) in your redux store and populate the typeahead with the value on the given page.

```
// Get the initial value from the store. This should be an array.
const typeaheadSelections = useSelector(...);

<Typeahead
  ...
  onChange={(selected) => {
    // Update the value in the store when the selection changes.
    dispatch({
      type: 'set-typeahead',
      value: selected,
    });
  }}
  selected={typeaheadSelections}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks once again ericgio! In the end I did it by dispatching the change on the `<MenuItem onClick={}/>` function, (not on the `onChange` because there's no need for it to be char to char, only when items are selected) and then reading it when the component is rendered.

Comment: @Nighto: You should use `onChange`, which is triggered when the *selection* changes, as opposed to `onInputChange`, which is triggered when the *input value* changes (and seems to be what you're referring to).

Comment: It worked with the `<MenuItem onClick />`, but that probably just triggers the `<Typeahead onChange />`. But with that change I'm now facing a bug: when the user tries to edit the text field, it would always go back to the `selected` value.

Comment: Created a small gif: https://imgur.com/a/jX4Gwj5

Comment: Managed to "unlock" it by dispatching the change on the `onInputChange`. Re-reading, maybe that's exactly what you've mentioned. Thanks once again! :)

Comment: I am still confused. If I set the value on the `selected` attribute, then I have some text on the input, if I try to change it it goes back to the `selected` value as the gif above, but the `onChange` function receives an empty array as argument. On the other hand the `onInputChange` updates the `selected` value but then breaks the component as it will not fetch options anymore.

Comment: If I change it to `null` or `[]` on `onChange`, I can then change the input value, but as soon as I try to edit something the text disappears.
I'm also getting this error, don't know what it means `Warning: [react-bootstrap-typeahead] You are changing an uncontrolled typeahead to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled element for the lifetime of the component.`

Comment: I'm not sure what your code looks like at this point, but again, I would advise using `onChange` and `selected`. `onInputChange` tracks the input value, as opposed to the selected item.

Comment: Hey ericgio, just posted a new question, if you could have a look it'd be very much appreciated once again <3 Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74612805/react-bootstrap-typeahead-cache-false-behavior-on-backspace-when-selected-value