# react-bootstrap-typeahead cache=false behavior on backspace when selected value is prefilled

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

I think I'm hitting some sort of edge case here. [As mentioned on that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74405298/keep-two-react-bootstrap-typeahead-inputs-in-sync) I have two rbt instances that are kept sync by the `selected` attribute. When the component is "fresh" (i.e. no `selected` value prefilled), if the user writes a search string, in this case an address (number street, city) and then changes the number by erasing one character, it works as expected:

[image: search working on backspace]

However on another rbt instance, where the searched value is prefilled as the `selected` attribute, it does not perform the search when the user erases one character, only when they type a character again (and only then it refreshes on backspace):

[image: search not working on backspace]

Any suggestions on how could I fix this?

P.S.: you have been very helpful and your help is much appreciated. Do you have some way of supporting your work? Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: can you please post a sandbox link or code examples?